# Reload datatable data with ajax call on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a datatable with ajax calls. I form the table like this:

```
var _initTable = function() {
    $('#datatables tr').not(':first').on('click', function() {
        var dateandtime = $(this).find(':nth-child(3)').text();
        window.location.href = '/results/detail/dateandtime/' + dateandtime;
    });
};

$('#datatables').dataTable({
     bProcessing  : true,
     sProcessing  : true,
     bServerSide  : true,
     sAjaxSource  : '/results/load-results',
     fnServerParams: function ( aoData ) {
         aoData.push( {"name": "quizid", "value": quizid },{ "name": "questionid", "value": questionid } );
     },
     aoColumnDefs : [{'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : ['no-sort']}], // make the actions column unsortable
     sPaginationType : 'full_numbers',
     fnDrawCallback  : function(oSettings) {
         _initTable();
     }
});
```

As you can see I send 2 parameters to my php action. 
Now I would like to reload the table when I click on a button. So what I want to do is make another ajax call and send other parameters (quizid will be the same, but the questionid will be different).

I know you have something like this `oTable.fnReloadAjax(newUrl);` but what should I paste at the newUrl parameter??

I've made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8TwS7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should be able to accomplish this by using fnServerData instead of fnServerParams

```
var oTable = $('#datatables').dataTable({
     bProcessing  : true,
     sProcessing  : true,
     bServerSide  : true,
     sAjaxSource  : '/results/load-results',
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
            /* Add some extra data to the sender */
            aoData.push( { "name": "quizid", "value": quizid } );
            aoData.push( { "name": "question_id", "value": question_id } );
            $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function () { 
                /* Do whatever additional processing you want on the callback, then tell DataTables */              
            }).done(function(json){
                fnCallback(json);
                        }).fail(function(xhr, err){ 
                var responseTitle= $(xhr.responseText).filter('title').get(0);
                alert($(responseTitle).text() + "\n" + formatErrorMessage(xhr, err) ); 
            });
        },      
    });
```

you should be able to then call a click function to redraw your table no problem using the fnDraw API call on the variable we created on datatable initialization

```
$('#somelement').on('click', function(){

        oTable.fnDraw();
    });
```

Comment: Then I just get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oFeatures' of null

Comment: you will have to post your entire source via jsfiddle in order to troubleshoot that...something is out of whack and without looking at all your source code i would only be guessing

Comment: Ok, I've made a jsfiddle. It doesn't work and the links aren't correctly but you can see how my code looks like ... http://jsfiddle.net/8TwS7/

Comment: take php out of the equation...what does "/results/load-results" return? I am guessing right now that the aaData is misformed, scroll down on this page to server response, it should match this format http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html

Comment: Nowp, it's correct and just the same as the original response (but different data ofcourse). Here's and updated topic of my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005816/double-ajax-call-when-reloading-datatable

Comment: youre not understanding what i'm saying...the jsfiddle you created is not useful as there are too many server-side declarations that are not included in the jsfiddle...for instance <?php echo json_encode($quizid); ?> is never declared in any of your source thats provided, is that just a get variable?. I have no problem attempting to troubleshoot this problem, but you are going to have to decouple the php logic and provide a static data array that you are expecting when /loadresults/ is called, that way it can be diagnosed...does that make sense?