# Double ajax call when reloading datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a datatable intialised like this:

```
var _initTable = function() {
    $('#datatablesresults tr').not(':first').on('click', function() {
        var dateandtime = $(this).find(':nth-child(3)').text();
        window.location.href = '/results/detail/dateandtime/' + dateandtime;
    });
};

$('#datatablesresults').dataTable({
    bProcessing  : true,
    sProcessing  : true,
    bServerSide  : true,
    sAjaxSource  : '/results/load-results',
    fnServerParams: function ( aoData ) {
        aoData.push( {"name": "quizid", "value": quizid },{ "name": "questionid", "value": questionid } );
    },
    aoColumnDefs : [{'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : ['no-sort']}], // make the actions column unsortable
    sPaginationType : 'full_numbers',
    fnDrawCallback  : function(oSettings) {
        _initTable();
    }
});
```

When I click on a button I want to reload the data in the table (make an ajax call)

```
$('.carousel-control.right').click(function() {
    var currentquestion = $('#myCarousel .active').index('#myCarousel .item') + 1;
    var question = currentquestion + 1;

    var quizid = <?= json_encode($quizid); ?>;

    var activediv = $('.item').filter('.active');
    var questionid = activediv.index() + 2;

    var questionclass = ".question" + questionid;

    var questionid = $(questionclass).attr("id");

    var getParams = "quizid=" + quizid +"&questionid=" + questionid;

    $("#datatablesresults").dataTable().fnReloadAjax("/results/load-results?" + getParams);
});
```

But the data stays the same ... Here you see my ajax calls:
[image]

The first is when my page is loaded. The second is my ajax refresh, the data that's resend is different then the other. But then you see there's another ajax call that overwrites the data ... :/

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I've made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8TwS7/

Comment: Assigning to `window.location.href` reloads the page, could that be it?

Comment: That's only when you click on a row in the table. And I'm 100% sure the page doesn't reload.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to use .dataTable() once you already defined it.

First assign the datatable to a variable:

```
var myDataTable = $('#datatablesresults').dataTable({
    bProcessing  : true,
    sProcessing  : true,
    bServerSide  : true,
    sAjaxSource  : '/results/load-results',
    fnServerParams: function ( aoData ) {
        aoData.push( {"name": "quizid", "value": quizid },{ "name": "questionid", "value": questionid } );
    },
    aoColumnDefs : [{'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : ['no-sort']}], // make the actions column unsortable
    sPaginationType : 'full_numbers',
    fnDrawCallback  : function(oSettings) {
        _initTable();
    }
});
```

Then just use fnReloadAjax on that variable to refresh it:

```
myDataTable.fnReloadAjax("/results/load-results?" + getParams);
```

Comment: Can you populate the table with some dummy data in your jsfiddle? It's kinda hard to tell whats going on here. I would trim your code to the minimum example needed to get things going

Comment: I was having an issue with 2 xhr requests per page load. Dropped the `ServerSide` argument completely and it stopped. Seems assigning `ajaxSource` was more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

when you call this line

```
$("#datatablesresults").dataTable().fnReloadAjax("/results/load-results?" + getParams);
```

you are re-initializing the datatables again

place your datatables() in the doc ready in a variable, then call fnDraw() to redraw the table...like i answered in your other question [Reload datatable data with ajax call on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003316/reload-datatable-data-with-ajax-call-on-click)

if you need more help post your entire js code and i'll show you

Comment: Then I just get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oFeatures' of null

Comment: you will have to post your entire source via jsfiddle in order to troubleshoot that...something is out of whack and without looking at all your source code i would only be guessing